# Can't refresh timescaledb continuous aggregate with refresh_continuous_aggregate where start and end intervals are NULL

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I use timescaledb 2.9.3 and I have a simple hypertable:

```sql
CREATE TABLE metrics
(
    time      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    value     INT
);
SELECT create_hypertable('metrics', 'time');
```

I inserted some data and created two materialized only views:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS metrics_hourly
WITH (timescaledb.continuous, timescaledb.materialized_only=true)
AS
SELECT time_bucket('1 hour', time) as hour, sum(value)
FROM metrics
GROUP BY hour
WITH NO DATA;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS metrics_monthly
WITH (timescaledb.continuous, timescaledb.materialized_only=true)
AS
SELECT time_bucket('1 month', time) as month, sum(value)
FROM metrics
GROUP BY month
WITH NO DATA;
```

When I try to update `metrics_hourly` with

```sql
call refresh_continuous_aggregate('metrics_hourly', NULL, NULL);
```

it's ok and updated well

When I try to update `metrics_monthly` the same way

```sql
call refresh_continuous_aggregate('metrics_monthly', NULL, NULL);
```

I've got an error:

```
ERROR:  timestamp out of range
SQL state: 22008
```

I should specify start or end to make it work, for example:

```sql
call refresh_continuous_aggregate('metrics_monthly', '2021-01-01', NULL);
```

Why I can't use both start and end as NULL for monthly view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just provide `'-infinite'` and `now()` to refresh it:

```
CALL refresh_continuous_aggregate(
    '<<cagg_name>>',
    window_start := '-infinity'::timestamptz,
    window_end := now()
);
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do like this. But why I can't just use NULL, according to the docs it's equivalent to MIN(timestamp) and MAX(timestamp).
NULL value works well in views with bucket by hour, day and week, but not by months and years

Comment: I don't think there's isn't any reason other than "that's not how it is built". It's probably perfectly possible to implement that, but what is the big difference?